# Well the issue is this, why is the value type as I have written it not able to write out to the String?

Tags: swift

**Code I have tried :**

```
class Panagram {

    let consoleID = ConsoleID()


    func getOption(_option: String) -> (option:OptionType, value: String) {
        return (OptionType(value: option), option) //The error is on this line //
    }
```

**Error:**

> Cannot convert value of type 'option.type' to expected argument type
>   'String'

Comment: Can you show me more of the code? What is that OptionType you are expecting? Try to add a space between your underscore and the option like this: "(_ option: String)"

Answer (score 2):

Add a space between `_` and parameter name `option` in your function parameter. Currently param name is `_option` not `option`.

Try this.

```
func getOption(_ option: String) -> (option:OptionType, value: String) {
    return (OptionType(value: option), option) 
}
```